# How to scan the amount of integers within an ArrayList index

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program that checks an ArrayList and makes sure that each index includes only 2 integers per line, and doesn't include any doubles or strings.

If the arraylist is:

```
0 1
2 34
32 51 32
```

it would pull up an error message for the third line for having 3 integers. The program needs to check that it has only two integers per line, is only 12 lines long, and doesn't include any doubles or strings. This is what I have so far:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TextFileReader {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int fileCount = 0;

      ArrayList<String> inputFile = new ArrayList<String>(20);
      try (Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("perfect_file.txt"))) {
         while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
            inputFile.add(fileScanner.nextLine());

         }
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         System.out.println("Error reading generic answers, program ending.");
          System.exit(1);
      }




      if (inputFile.size() > 12) {
         System.out.println("Error: Lines exceed 12");
      }
      if (inputFile.size() < 12) {
         System.out.println("Error: Not enough lines");
      }
   }
}
```

I would really appreciate any help on this. Thank you!

Comment: I think you'll find it helpful to use .split on the strings in each line.

Comment: You created a fileScanner to get all the lines. Now why not an intScanner for each line to get the ints? p.s. nextX and hasNextX should always match the X

Answer (score 0):

Use String [split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)), it's look like

```
try (Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("perfect_file.txt"));) {
    while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String[] line = fileScanner.nextLine().split("\\s+");
        if (line.length == 2) {
            // Ok, do something
            // System.out.println("First: " + line[0] + ", Second: " + line[1]);
        } else {
            // Wrong
            System.out.println("The number of line " + line.length);
        }
    }
}
```